# OpenSSL smime command creates different output than my java code

Tags: java, openssl, digital-signature, smime

I created a key pair in my key store and using this pair I wanted to create Java equivalent code of the following curl command.

```
openssl smime -sign -in req.xml -nointern -nodetach -nocerts -nochain -outform PEM \
  -out req_signed.txt -signer you.cer -inkey private.key -passin pass:HIDDEN
```

And my Java method is like following:

```java
public byte[] sign(boolean includeCerts) throws GeneralSecurityException, OperatorCreationException, CMSException, IOException {

    try {
        java.security.cert.Certificate[] certChain = KeyStoreUtil.getCertificateChainCombined(alias);
        if (certChain == null || certChain.length < 1)
            throw new GeneralSecurityException("Certificate chain was null or empty for alias \"" + alias + "\"");

        List<java.security.cert.Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<java.security.cert.Certificate>();
        for (int i = 0; i < certChain.length; i++)
            certList.add(certChain[i]);

        certs = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certList), "BC");
        priv = KeyStoreUtil.getPrivateKeyCombined(alias,"GwHwYQbeSLK6jES47wRR3fk1j");
        storecert = KeyStoreUtil.getCertificateCombined(alias);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
        log.warn("Problem with keystore access: " + gse.toString());
        throw gse;
    }

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Private Key Format: " + priv.getFormat());
        if (!Runmode.isLive()) {
            log.debug("Certificate for alias \"" + alias + "\" (encoded):\n" + LogUtil.encryptForLog(storecert.toString().getBytes(Constants.C_ASCII)));
        }
    }

    /*
     * Signing based on code from http://i-proving.ca/space/Technologies/JCE/PKCS7+Signatures+using+Bouncy+Castle
     */
    CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

    // Add signer info generator (actual signing will be done after)
    ContentSigner sha256Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(priv);
    DigestCalculatorProvider digestCalculatorProvider = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build();
    generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(digestCalculatorProvider).build(sha256Signer, (X509Certificate)storecert));

    if (includeCerts) {
        // Add certificates used for signing
        List<X509Certificate> certificates = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
        certificates.add((X509Certificate)storecert);
        generator.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(certificates));
    }

    // NOTE: IOUtils handles large files by copying bytes in blocks of 4MB
    CMSTypedData content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
    org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData signedData = generator.generate(content, true);

    if (!Runmode.isLive()) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            String asn1Dump = ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(signedData.toASN1Structure(), true);
            log.debug("CMSSignedData ASN.1 dump (encoded):\n" + LogUtil.encryptForLog(asn1Dump.getBytes(Constants.C_ASCII)));
        }
    }

    return signedData.getEncoded();
}
```

But the output of OpenSSL and Java are different. I made a lot of search, but i couldn't get anywhere. I would like to say that I am not familiar with digital signing.

Is there anything wrong with my code? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Replicating 'openssl smime' in Java with Bouncy Castle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12732275/608639) on Stack Overflow and [What is the Java equivalent of "openssl smime binary"?](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/What-is-the-Java-equivalent-of-quot-openssl-smime-binary-quot-td21300.html) on the OpenSSL user list.

Comment: I already tried it in my code.But it creates different.output of curl command starts with -----BEGIN PKCS7----- and ends with -----END PKCS7-----. I suspect that i am applying proper logic in JAVA code.Because output of java code doesn't start with -----BEGIN PKCS7-----  

I am really stucked